# Почему "параллелограмм" с двумя М?

Tags: этимология

Почему в слове "параллелограмм" в конце пишется два "м"? В справочнике по математике Бронштейна и Семендяева это слово пишется с одним "м", и,по-моему, это правильно. Зачем там это весовое окончание? Более того, может, это слово вообще правильнее было бы писать "параллелограф"? Причём там "грамм" или "грам"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Из греческого. Грамма в одном из значений - линия.
(др.-греч. παραλληλόγραμμον от παράλληλος — параллельный и γραμμή — линия)
(Вики).

Comment: Кстати, есть еще монограмма, телеграмма и грамматика. Там какие "граммы"?  В двух последних случаях просматривается смысл "буква" или "слово". В первом, в принципе, это тоже может быть. Но и линия подходит.

Comment: Здесь, насколько понимаю, везде - "буква". 
Вообще значение у слова в древнегреческом было весьма широкое. Общий смысл - то что (может быть) начертано. Так что продуктивность заимствованной основы неудивительна.